# Display locations based on KML file in Bing Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, kml

Currently i am using the following code to display locations on a map in my application:

```
    //Bustop 8448 – 

    Pushpin BusStop8448 = new Pushpin();
    BusStop8448.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    BusStop8448.Location = new GeoCoordinate(-36.934608, 174.73016);
    BusStop8448.Content = "Bus Stop: 8448 ";
    BusStop8448.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(BusStop8448_MouseLeftButtonUp);
    var BusStop8448Press = sender as Pushpin;


    this.Map.Children.Add(BusStop8448);
```

This is very tedious as there are hundreds of locations to add, so I was thinking about displaying locations based on a KML file.

My question is how do I display pushpins based on a KML file in windows phone 7 Bing Maps?

Also, I would like to know if there is a way of having an Onclick event for each of these pushpins from the KML file.

Currently I am using the below code which works file, but I 'm not sure how I would implemented that with KML based pushpins

```
void BusStop8679_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    int id = 8679;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DepartureBoard.xaml?ListingId=" + id, UriKind.Relative));           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse the coordinates in the KML file (using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org) or a XML de-serializer would make it very easy), then use [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to bind the coordinate list to the view, and use a [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) to customize the pushpin itself.

You can then attach a event listener for the [Tap event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Set the `Tag` property to `{Binding}` , and read it out in the Tap element, and then you can access the element you clicked.