# adding custom Cartographical Model to a map in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

How can i add a custom Cartographical Model to a map in WP8

example: in order to add a map with a Cartographical Mode of "Aerial" i uses the following code in written XAML:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="myMap" CartographicMode="Aerial"/>
```

and the provided Cartographical Model of the maps in the WP8 SDK are:

[image]

so how can i add a custom one to my map;

Comment: This might get you started : [KML in Bing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451332/display-locations-based-on-kml-file-in-bing-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a custom CartographicMode directly but you can add a custom tile layer to the map and use that as your custom CartographicMode. To do this you can create a TileSource

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.tilesource(v=vs.105).aspx

Once this is created you can add it to the TileSources property of the map:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.tilesources(v=vs.105).aspx